# Is genome recurrence possible like in Jupiter Ascending?

Tags: genetics, gene

I have watched Jupiter Ascending many times now and I was wondering if [genome recurrence](http://jupiter-ascending.wikia.com/wiki/Recurrence), like what happened to Jupiter Jones, is possible.

Is it possible to find two unrelated people, possibly several generations apart, that cannot be distinguished between by DNA sequencing?

Taking the example of Jupiter Ascending: in the movie Seraphi Abrasax they show the "genetic recurrence" of Jupiter Jones, which means the same sequence of DNA has repeated after several thousand years from Seraphi to Jupiter.

Comment: Could you expand on "genetic code recurrence like what happened to Jupiter Jones". This is new to me. It sounds like you are asking "is it possible for unrelated people to be genetically identical?" Technically possible. Statistically, however, nigh on impossible.

Comment: @James I'm directing you to this wikia http://jupiter-ascending.wikia.com/wiki/Recurrence for more information.

Comment: I got the gist of it. For all intents and purposes, it's impossible.

Comment: I have edited this post, especially the title, to replace ["Genetic Code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code) by ["Genome"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome). If you do not understand the difference between the two, follow the links I have provided.

Comment: @James if you understood the question, do you think you could try to clarify it by editing the question but I don't understand the question!

Comment: @Remi.b It's fantastical and loaded by saying "is it possible" (anything is possible given enough imagination), but I've tried to edit my interpretation into the question. Richeve, if I have changed the meaning of the question, please do roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various types of genetic variation exist in natural populations. One is the [single-nucleotide polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) (SNP), which is where different nucleotides are present at the same location in the genome of different individuals in a population (with variation present in a nontrivial number of people; the threshold is usually set arbitrarily at 1%).

Even just considering SNPs and ignoring other types of variation, what you talk about would be effectively impossible.

The human genome is about 3 billion base-pairs long. Along the whole genome, according to Chen et al 2012, between two individuals there is something like [3 million SNPs](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?&id=110117). Imagine two people flipping a coin and the result is exactly the same every time, 3 million times. Now imagine instead of heads or tails, there are 4 options.

Only 1 result of the series of 3 million 1 in 4 chances is identical to the original series.

$\frac{1}{4^{3000000}}\approx\frac{1}{\infty}$ = 0

Go ahead, try it on your calculator.

Now, there are also variations that are beyond SNPs between individuals that cause much more variation between two people. These can cause even more "unprobability". Since we already require infinite people before this event is likely to happen, **I think we can just call this event impossible**.

Comment: 3 Gbp is 3 billion, not 3 million, so the odds are even lower. It's not = to $1/\inf$ though. Its still finite, its just vanishingly small if we are being pedantic :P

Comment: That we need infinite people does not make it mathematically impossible (as you state in a comment), but biologically (or generally, practically) impossible.

Comment: @JoeHealey I was coming at it from the point of a comparison between 2 people: of the 3 Gbp in their genomes, 3 million bp are likely to be SNPs from one person to the other. The likelihood that those SNPs are the same is an incalculably small number (at least, according to my calculator :P).

Comment: Ah I see what you meant, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible. Considering that the haploid Human genome is around 3 Gb (Giga-basepairs) and that ideally any of those can mutate generation after generation, the chance of having the very same sequence recurring in a population is extremely unlikely. There will be some differences.

Comment: I was thinking that your term "population" refers only to Earth, but in the movie, the population refers to their "planet farms" and they have many seeded planets that uses their own genetic code as the base to construct new sets of modified human beings. So with these large set of population it is still not possible?

Comment: Still, you have 4^3giga possibilities (roughly speaking). Even having the whole universe and billions of years it will be an "almost-zero" chance of having two identical sequences. Unless you interfere with technology, some cloning-like tech for example. But if we stick to natural reproduction, then the chances are ridiculously low.

Comment: I was trying to picture this mathematically, like if you have a finite set of bases and the DNA sequence which is long but non-continuous which means there's a limit to its length then any sequence with finite set of elements and constant length can have a possibility of repetition even if the generation is random. The chances is almost zero but not zero which means there's still a possibility. Since Earth is a closed space and considering we haven't tapped yet to cloning, or haven't introduce synthetic bases to our DNAs then our DNA set is still finite and thus repetition is still possible.

Comment: Mathematically possible, practically impossible. That's why my answer states "almost impossible".